# Code Signing Errors When Compiling C++ From Unreal Engine 4 in Xcode 5.1

Tags: c++, xcode, unreal-engine4

I created a few C++ files in Unreal Engine 4, and imported the project in Xcode to compile the new files. When I attempt to build, it fails, giving me the following errors:

```
Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Developer” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

I do NOT have a paid iOS or Mac Developer license. I am doing this solely for hobby purposes at the moment, however, that shouldn't prevent me from compiling the code for Unreal, should it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I am NOT trying to deploy to a device at the moment. All I am doing, is trying to compile a couple very small .cpp files that were created for UE4. The game engine cannot compile them, so it opened up a project in Xcode for me automatically.

EDIT 2: The project settings are already set to "Don't Code Sign".

Answer (score 0):

Code Signing is required for building and deploying iOS apps on devices. If you're just building for the simulator, you don't need to code sign.

Change the project settings under `Build Settings` (click the project file and click "Build Settings along the top bar") from whatever the imported project has to `Don't Code Sign`.

[image: Disabling code signing]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and found that the the first line within the project settings window has a drop down that is probably set to the UE4XcodeHelper target. If you click this, you will then see the main project as well as a number of targets. You need to navigate to each target, then the Code Signing section and make sure that 'Don't Code Sign' is set for each target. Then you can build without that interruption.